# How to parameterize table name in oracle sql procedure || export table method

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to take an export of a table from oracle database to a csv. For that i have prepared some code. Now this code is based on that particular table base. I wanted to make this dynamic. Is that possible to edit this code so that we can pass the table name only and get the same output respectively?

```
SET ECHO OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET LINESIZE 9999
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TIMING OFF
SET TIME OFF
set serveroutput ON
SPOOL C:\temp\output.csv
declare
    v_heading varchar2(4000);
begin
    for cur in (select column_name,column_id from user_tab_cols where table_name='NDR_AVTALE_TYPER' and COLUMN_NAME not like '%SYS%' order by column_id) loop
        if cur.column_id > 1 then
            v_heading := v_heading ||',';
        end if;
        v_heading := v_heading || cur.column_name;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_heading);
    for cur in (select AVTALE_TYPE, BESKRIVELSE, TABELL, HISTORIKK, DOKUMENTER from NDR_AVTALE_TYPER order by 1,2) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(cur.AVTALE_TYPE||','||cur.BESKRIVELSE||','||cur.TABELL||','||cur.HISTORIKK||','||cur.DOKUMENTER);
    end loop;
end;
/
SPOOL OFF
disconnect
quit
```

output of this is like

```
SQL> @C:\temp\Export_oracle_table.sql
AVTALE_TYPE,BESKRIVELSE,TABELL,HISTORIKK,DOKUMENTER,GEOM
1,Gatelysavtale,NDR_GATELYS_AVTALE,J,J
2,LinjetrasΘavtale,NDR_TRASE_AVTALE,J,J
```

Comment: Have you tried using Dynamic SQL?

Comment: As you're using SQL Developer, you could do `set sqlformat csv` and then just query the table directly and get CSV output, without needing to use PL/SQL. That will also wrap strings in double quotes, which is helpful if they might contain commas - but depends what you're going to do with the CSV file.

Comment: i cannot use sql developper, as i need to schedule this sql file. so daily it will export the csv. so i created a batch file and i am calling this sql from that. then i added this task in task schedular. But the problem is not that. they came up with multiple table export. which means i have to create all the different column details to get the export. if i can pass the table name only and get the same output that i am looking here. or if you have some other solution for that.

Comment: Then why did you *tag* this with SQL Developer? Adding irrelevant tags doesn't help anybody. But you can do the same thing with the SQLcl client, in place of (presumably) SQL\*Plus. You can even pass in the table name as a positional argument, and `select * from &1;` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

With `SET HEAD ON` you will have the heading without printing.
If you do the SELECT statement out of block you will get your data in a file.

Comment: i tried that before. but still not getting the header. and the output is looks different.

Comment: The problem is because your fields size are not defined as well, instead of call each column separated by column. do:
SELECT FIELD1 || ';' || FIELD2 ... FIELDN FROM ...